# How to check whether constraint_exclusion is enabled or not in my database?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

As per [official Postgres documents](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-CONSTRAINT-EXCLUSION) default value of constraint_exclusion is "partition". How can I ensure this? Is there any way to check current value from PgAdmin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SHOW](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-show.html) will display the current setting of run-time parameters.

```
Show constraint_exclusion;
```